# MVC.NET Custom Root Handler Wrong action in Html:BeginForm

Tags: forms, asp.net-mvc-4, custom-routes, html.beginform, mvcroutehandler

I used custom mvc route handler. But When I use Html.BeginForm or Ajax.BeginForm in the view, Action parameters change unexpectedly. My codes are above

My Register Route method is :

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute("alias",
                        "{alias}",
                        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
                        ).RouteHandler = new FriendlyUrlRoutehandler();


        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional} // Parameter defaults
            );
    }
```

My MvcRouteHandler is :

```
public class FriendlyUrlRoutehandler : MvcRouteHandler
{
    protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        var friendlyUrl = (string)requestContext.RouteData.Values["alias"];

        if (friendlyUrl != null)
        {
            if (friendlyUrl.Equals("man-parfume"))
            {
                requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "ManParfume";
                requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = "Index";
            }
            else if (friendlyUrl.Equals("ring"))
            {
                requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "Ring";
                requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = "Index";
            }
            else if (friendlyUrl.Equals("glases"))
            {
                requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "Categories";
                requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = "Index";
                requestContext.RouteData.Values["id"] = 10;
            }
        }

        return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
    }
}
```

My View is :

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post" }))
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
```

Finally wrong action in browser looks like this :

> form action="/man-parfume" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="Post" id="form0" method="post">    
>   form action="/man-parfume" method="post">     input type="submit" value="send" />

I wrote controller as a home in begin form but it changed when Html.BeginForm rendered.

How can I post the form to Home/Index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `<form action="@Url.RouteUrl("Default", new { controller="Home", action="Index"}" method="post">` instead `Html.BeginForm`.

As to `Ajax.BeginForm` it may be changed on jQuery function:

```
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "@Url.RouteUrl("Default", new { controller="Home", action="Index"}",
      data: data,
      success: success,
      dataType: dataType
    });
```

Comment: Thank you ok it is work but do you have any idea why Html.BeginForm isn't working?

Comment: @sta you have two routes to similar Action: defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }. "alias" comes first in you route map, so Html.BeginForm takes it as route for its action. But to my mind it should work anyway. May be somthing wrong in your controller action?

Comment: it is  working. However form post to own controller. My expectation that it post to my wished controller and action. is there any way to change route map of Html.BeginForm? Can I set different from BeginForm selected?