# Asp.net Mvc html form is posted to wrong controller action

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller with 2 actions:

```
public class OrganizationUnitsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        // return empty form
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(OrganizationUnitViewModel unitViewModel)
    {
        // Save the new unit to the DB
        return View();
    }
}
```

The **Create.cshtml** is:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "OrganizationUnits", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "form", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{

    <!-- Some inputs -->

    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Save</a>
}

$('#form')
.on('submit',function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Save", "OrganizationUnits")',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                      Name: $('#Name').val(),
                      Admin: JSON.stringify({ 'FullDescription': $('#Admin').val() }),
                      Members: JSON.stringify( $('#users_list_box').val() )
            });
});
```

The problem is when i click the save button, the javascript code which makes the unitViewModel and pass the form to *Save action* not invoked and the *Create* action is invoked.

Changing the controller action in the **@Html.BeginForm()** to null doesn't solved the problem.

How can i fix it?

Comment: How does your form tag looks like in the generated html? Post the html generated by the create action method.

Comment: Also check the Network tab (IE Dev tools) and observe the URL requested when you click the button.

Comment: You do not have a submit button (just a link that makes a GET)

Comment: Just a tip, use $('#yourFormId').serialize() instead of JSON.strigify({}). Makes your life a lot easier and code easier to maintain

Comment: Delete you `<a>` and replace with `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC.NET Custom Root Handler Wrong action in Html:BeginForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249789/mvc-net-custom-root-handler-wrong-action-in-htmlbeginform)

Comment: This line is invalid `url: '@Url.Action("Save", "OrganizationUnits")',`. You can't use the Razor html helper inside the JS script file.

Comment: @Thangadurai, Its perfectly fine (the script is not in an external file)

Comment: @Thangadurai the Save link address is `OrganizationUnit/Create`, despite i set the href to empty

Comment: @StephenMuecke, will it work even if the JS file is an external file?

Comment: @StephenMuecke The reason i used <a> is i wanted to process some inputs and make the argument when invoking the Save action

Comment: @Thangadurai, No, but that is irrelevant in this case (OP script is never executed anyway because the form does not have a submit button - just a `<a>` which makes a GET back to the same method that generated the view)

Comment: @ehsantoghian - making it a `<a>` or a submit button makes no difference in regard to that - you can still process whatever you want

Comment: ok, then probably your script is not at all executed as mentioned by @StephenMuecke. You need to include a 'submit' button instead of the <a href> tag

Comment: @Thangadurai you where right. When i change the url to '/OrganizationUnit/Save' the right action is invoked as well. But it makes the code fragile. Is there a better solution to not hard code it?

Comment: @ehsantoghian, Your last comment has nothing to do with the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stephen Muecke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke)'s correct `<a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Save</a>` is problematic, and click on it causes a `GET`, try replacing it with `submit` input type.

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
```

and use `e.preventDefault();` because `stopPropagation` stops the event from bubbling up the event chain,
whereas `preventDefault` prevents the default action the browser makes on that event.

```
$('#form').on('submit',function (e) {
    var actionUrl = this.action;
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: actionUrl,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({
                  Name: $('#Name').val(),
                  Admin: JSON.stringify({ 'FullDescription': $('#Admin').val() }),
                  Members: JSON.stringify( $('#users_list_box').val() )
        });
});
```

Comment: Your answer is almost right, the issue is the wrong ajax url. If you correct it the problem is solved completely

Answer (score 0):

This may not be YOUR cause, but I encountered the same problem.

My problem was that there was an [Authorize] attribute on the controller but the action called did not have the [AllowAnonymous] attribute.